# Set up Envoy as a reverse proxy inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, dns, reverse-proxy, envoyproxy

I'm attempting to learn more about, and set up Envoy (using a Docker image) as a reverse proxy.

```
Requests → Docker container running Envoy → Proxy to a different server based on the request.
```

I'm running into what seems to be an issue resolving the proxy addresses. Here's what I see when I access `localhost:8080`.

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure
```

### Envoy Configurations

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM envoyproxy/envoy:v1.18.3
COPY envoy-custom.yaml /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
RUN chmod go+r /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```

The Envoy configuration, `envoy-custom.yaml`, using a simplified version of the [example here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.18.3/configuration/best_practices/edge.html). It's listening on port `8080`, and attempting to proxy to an internal server. For simplicity, it's currently set to proxy all requests.

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8080
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: gateway
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: targetCluster
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config: {}

  clusters:
    - name: targetCluster
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: LOGICAL_DNS
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: frontend
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      # address: host.docker.internal
                      # address: some-address-inside-a-corp-network
                      # For the purposes of this post, proxying 
                      # to Google
                      address: google.com
                      port_value: 80
```

The Envoy configuration appears to be V3 compliant.

```
$ docker run --rm \
  -v (pwd)/envoy.custom.yaml:/my-envoy-config.yaml \
  envoyproxy/envoy:v1.18.3 \
  --mode validate \
  -c my-envoy-config.yaml


[2021-05-20 17:30:35.544][1][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:667] runtime: layers:
  - name: base
    static_layer:
      {}
  - name: admin
    admin_layer:
      {}
[2021-05-20 17:30:35.544][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:128] loading tracing configuration
[2021-05-20 17:30:35.544][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:88] loading 0 static secret(s)
[2021-05-20 17:30:35.544][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:94] loading 1 cluster(s)
[2021-05-20 17:30:35.545][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:98] loading 1 listener(s)
configuration 'my-envoy-config.yaml' OK
[2021-05-20 17:30:35.547][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:110] loading stats configuration
```

The Envoy logs on debug mode:

```
...
[2021-05-20 17:15:02.991][1][debug][upstream] [source/common/upstream/upstream_impl.cc:279] transport socket match, socket default selected for host with address [2607:f8b0:4007:804::200e]:80
[2021-05-20 17:15:02.991][1][debug][upstream] [source/common/upstream/strict_dns_cluster.cc:170] DNS refresh rate reset for google.com, refresh rate 5000 ms
[2021-05-20 17:15:07.960][1][debug][upstream] [source/common/upstream/upstream_impl.cc:279] transport socket match, socket default selected for host with address [2607:f8b0:4007:804::200e]:80
[2021-05-20 17:15:07.960][1][debug][upstream] [source/common/upstream/strict_dns_cluster.cc:170] DNS refresh rate reset for google.com, refresh rate 5000 ms
...
```

For what it's worth, I'm able to successfully achieve proxying using Nginx, using these configurations.

The `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  0.0.0.0;

    location / {
      # Testing if proxying is working locally; seems to be
      # proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:9090;

      # Testing if proxying to a corp server is working; seems to be
      # proxy_pass some-address-inside-a-corp-network

      # For the purposes of this post, proxying to Google
      proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
    }
}
```

The `Dockerfile` for setting up Nginx:

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

### Question

Am I missing something in my configurations, that's preventing Envoy from proxying?

Comment: Velan seems to be [facing a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630755/unable-to-access-host-port-from-docker-containerenvoy), but on a different cluster type (`strict_dns`) configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the log you posted the upstream address is resolved in IP v6, try limiting it to v4 in https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.18.3/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/cluster.proto#enum-config-cluster-v3-cluster-dnslookupfamily. Also, don’t know if it’s a factor but you’re proxying Nginx to port 443 of Google.com not 80 like in Envoy configuration.